# I want to calculate differnce between two times which are in 24 hours format

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, time, difference

I want answer in minutes

```
tv1 = timevalue({16:00:00 PM) 
tv2 = timevalue(19:00:00 PM) 

x=datediff("n",tv1, tv2)
```

x

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you times come from originally because `16:00:00 PM` is unusual. I would either expect `16:00:00` or `4:00:00 PM`. Having said that you can parse your string into a TimeSpan to easily calculate the difference:

```
    Dim time1 = TimeSpan.Parse("16:00:00")
    Dim time2 = TimeSpan.Parse("19:00:00")
    Dim timeDiff = time2 - time1
    Debug.WriteLine(timeDiff.ToString) ' prints 03:00:00
```

Just seen you want the answer in minutes so use:

```
timeDiff.TotalMinutes
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TimeSpan`:

```
Dim time1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(16)
Dim time2 = TimeSpan.FromHours(19)
Dim timeDiff As TimeSpan = time2 - time1
Dim minutes As Int32 = CInt( timeDiff.TotalMinutes ) ' 180
```

Comment: Not only did we come up with a very similar answer - but we used the same variable names - weird!

Comment: @MattWilko : Is this Illuminati?